# How to display product attributes in WooCommerce with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the entire shopping cart in a customized way, therefore I have to get access to the:

- Product Image
- Product Title
- Product Price
- Product Attributes

So far I managed to display everything but the attributes. This is my working code so far.

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );
           
            $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
            echo $getProductDetail->get_image(); 

            echo "<b>".$_product->get_title() .'</b>  <br> Anzahl: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
            /*attributes*/
            /* $available_variations = $_product->get_available_variations();
                foreach ($available_variations as $key => $value) {
                    echo "$key $value";
                }*/
                    
        }
?>
```

The last part about the attributes is not working can someone assist me and tell me how to access the attributes of each product in the cart and display them underneath?

Comment: Either use $_product->get_attribute( 'attributeid' ); //get specific attribute value or $_product->get_attributes(); // get all attributes . Read this - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-cart-info-total-items-etc-from-cart-object/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've come so far that I don't get an error anymore. But I still can't get the color or size variation to be displayed.

Comment: `/*attributes*/
    $available_variations = $_product->get_attribute('pa_groese');
       
    echo "$available_variations";`

Comment: This is what I changed down at the part for the attributes

Comment: Attribute and variation are totaly different thing. Clarify what you want to output. And $available_variations  should be array ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
global $product;
echo wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
```

Comment: I suggest using the `$product->get_attributes();` instead.

Comment: When I do this I get a fatal error. Is it possible to only take certain attributes instead of all?